# How to show url in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I use `\usepackage{natbib}` and \bibliographystyle{apalike} to produce a bibliography in my book. The items of sources are built in a .bib file, in which an item is made as follows:

```
@incollection{MABh,
    Booktitle = {The Tibetan Tripitaka - Peking edition},
    Date-Added = {2016-10-01 20:30:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-11-15 13:34:00 +0000},
    Editor = {Suzuki, Daisetz T.},
    Key = {MABh},
    Pages = {for Peking 264b8-408b7 (p.108-166) And for Derge 220b1-348a7},
    Publisher = {Tokyo : Suzuki Research Foundation, 1962},
    Title = {Candrak{\=\i}rti's $D$bu Ma La 'Jug Pa'i Bshad Ba Shes Bya Ba (Tibetan translation of Madhyamak{\=a}vat{\=a}rabh{\=a}{\d s}ya)},
    url = "https://www.tbrc.org/#library_work_ViewByOutline-O1GS60111GS36115%7CW23703",
    Volume = {for Peking (Q 5263) dbu ma, 'a (vol.98) and for Derge (D 3862) dbu ma, 'a},
    Year = {1962}}
```

But when I print the bibliography with the command:

```
\bibliography{/Users/prinelo/Desktop/Database/mylib,/Users/prinelo/Desktop/Database/mylibtib}
```

the url does not show up.
I have tried another way to record the url information as:

```
howpublished = {\url{https://www.tbrc.org/#library_work_ViewByOutline-O1GS60111GS36115%7CW23703}},
```

it doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex` with option `[style=apa]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apalike` bibliography style has been around, more or less unchanged, since the early 1990s, when URLs were still pretty much unknown and just about nobody even considered the possibility of documents possibly being available online and being accessible through a web browser. (Thinking about it, the first widely available graphical web browser (called "netscape"?) wasn't distributed before 1994 or 1995...)

Probably unsurprisingly, then, the `apalike` bibliography has no knowledge of -- and therefore blithely ignores -- fields called `url`. If you can't switch to a different, i.e., more modern, bibliography style that does know what to do with fields called `url` , you should use the `note` field to provide the URL-related information -- and make sure that the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages are loaded.

Something like this (note the absence of the `url` field and the addition of the `note` field) may work for you:

```
@incollection{MABh,
  booktitle    = "The Tibetan Tripitaka---Peking edition",
  date-added   = "2016-10-01 20:30:51 +0000",
  date-modified= "2017-11-15 13:34:00 +0000",
  editor       = "Suzuki, Daisetz T.",
  key          = "MABh",
  pages        = "for Peking 264b8--408b7 (pp.\ 108--166) and for Derge
                  220b1--348a7",
  publisher    = "Tokyo: Suzuki Research Foundation",
  title        = "{Candrak{\=\i}rti's $D$bu Ma La 'Jug Pa'i Bshad Ba
                  Shes Bya Ba (Tibetan translation of
                  Madhyamak{\=a}vat{\=a}rabh{\=a}{\d s}ya)}",
  note         = "\url{https://www.tbrc.org/#library_work_ViewByOutline-O1GS60111GS36115%7CW23703}",
  volume       = "for Peking (Q~5263) dbu ma, 'a (vol.~98) and for
                  Derge (D~3862) dbu ma, 'a",
  year         = 1962,
}
```

---

A full MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@incollection{MABh,
  booktitle    = "The Tibetan Tripitaka---Peking edition",
  date-added   = "2016-10-01 20:30:51 +0000",
  date-modified= "2017-11-15 13:34:00 +0000",
  editor       = "Suzuki, Daisetz T.",
  key          = "MABh",
  pages        = "for Peking 264b8--408b7 (pp.\ 108--166) and for Derge
                  220b1--348a7",
  publisher    = "Tokyo: Suzuki Research Foundation",
  title        = "{Candrak{\=\i}rti's $D$bu Ma La 'Jug Pa'i Bshad Ba
                  Shes Bya Ba (Tibetan translation of
                  Madhyamak{\=a}vat{\=a}rabh{\=a}{\d s}ya)}",
  note         = "\url{https://www.tbrc.org/#library_work_ViewByOutline-O1GS60111GS36115%7CW23703}",
  volume       = "for Peking (Q~5263) dbu ma, 'a (vol.~98) and for
                  Derge (D~3862) dbu ma, 'a",
  year         = 1962,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\citet{MABh}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative reply and the practical sample. I am a very beginner to Latex. Indeed, I use {apalike} just because it comes from a template. I would much appreciate you if you can teach me more about "switch to a different, i.e., more modern, bibliography style".

Comment: @KingChungLo - One of the greatest things about BibTeX -- and the more modern `biblatex` package -- is that authors need spend very little time thinking about formatting bibliographies. All the author needs to do is select an appropriate bibliography style. When submitting a paper to a journal, there's usually a "house style" that *must* be used. E.g., for Elsevier-class journals, you'll probably have to use either `elsarticle-harv`, `elsarticle-num`, or `elarticle-num-names` -- the journal's submission guidelines will likely be quite clear on this point.

Comment: @KingChungLo - For a modern bibliography style that's in widespread use, consider the one of tha APA, 6th ed. For LaTeX authors, the APA's formatting guidelines can be implemented easily by loading the `apacite` package -- I recommend specifying the option `natbibapa` when loading `apacite`, i.e., `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` -- along with using the `apacite` bibliography style. See Table 3 on page 19 of the package's user guide for a complete listing of all bibliographic fields recognized by `apacite`.

Comment: Thanks again for the further introduction to apacite. Wow, a 102-page user's guide. I read it first and let you know if I have further question.